# How to encode MNIST data set on a quantum circuit to study supervised learning with QNN?

Tags: circuit-construction, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to implement [arXiv:1802.06002](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.06002)<sup>†</sup>. I do not understand how to take the data set from MNIST and apply it to a quantum circuit.

<sup>[†]: Classification with Quantum Neural Networks on Near Term Processors (Farhi & Neven, 2018)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, they reduce the size from 28*28 to 4*4 images (by [downsampling](https://www.giassa.net/?page_id=174)), then convert into binary values for pixels by just comparing to a value. Then, they encode the data in a quantum uniform superposition (with computational basis representing a bitstring data image with its label).

Comment: Can you speak more about encoding the downsampled image to be able to apply it to the quantum circuit?